# TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm getting this error in my React enzyme test - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined`

Below is my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import TransactionsTable from './TransactionsTable';

import Pagination from './Pagination';

it('contains a table', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<TransactionsTable />);
  expect(wrapper.find(Pagination)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
});
```

I can't see where my code differs from the solutions I've seen to this. Also, it seems in accordance with the docs. Anything I've missed?

UPDATE

I also tried fixing to the following (for Jest), but I huge output of red:

```
const wrapper = mount(<TransactionsTable />);
expect(wrapper.find(Pagination)).toHaveLength(1);
```

Error:

```
FAIL  src/components/includes/TransactionsTable.test.js
  ● <TransactionsTable /> › contains a table

    expect(received).toHaveLength(length)

    Expected value to have length:
      1
    Received:
      {Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): null, Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): {"batchedUpdates": [Function batchedUpdates], "getNode": [Function getNode], "render":...
```

It seems to be the correct method call now (toHaveLength) but am I passing in the Pagination component in wrong now?

Comment: Which test runner are you using?  mocha, jest, jasmine, ava, other?

Comment: I'm using Jest.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the error, you've got after you have used a valid matcher appears because enzyme cannot find `Pagination` component in `TransactionsTable`.
`toHaveLength` Jest matcher gives strange output when it fails while being used with enzyme wrapper.
Try to use the following statement

```
expect(wrapper.find(Pagination).length).toBe(1);
```

and I bet you will get an error that the expected value is `1` but `0` received.

PS: [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6519) is the issue in Jest repo about the strange output.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which test runner or assertion library you are using.

For Jest you want to use [toHaveLength](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavelengthnumber)

```
it('contains a table', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<TransactionsTable />);
  expect(wrapper.find(Pagination)).toHave.lengthOf(1);
});
```

Where as chai would be [to.have.lengthOf(1)](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_lengthof)

Comment: Hi. Thanks. That seems to have fixed the undefined, but I'm seeing a strange error now. I've updated my post.